# Two functions on Keypress won't work (textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, textarea

I have created two function on Enter Key press

1. to hide show dive on Enter key press
2. to auto resize textarea Height on Enter when it reached to end.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rz3f3gng/2/

```js
$('.one').hide();

$(function() {
  //hide show dive on enter press and on other keys hide div
  $('#mainContent').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.one').show();
    } else {
      $('.one').hide();
    }
  });

  function TextareaAuto(o) {
    o.style.height = "200px";
    o.style.height = (2 + o.scrollHeight) + "px";
  }
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
</div>

<textarea id="mainContent" onkeydown="TextareaAuto(this)" style="overflow:hidden">

</textarea>
```

Only One function seems to work at time, either Hide show div or auto size `textarea`.

Comment: My only question now is: Why did you have `e.preventDefault()` in the first place on Enter press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never mix inline event handlers with jQuery handlers. Just use two jQuery handlers or call the function from the existing handler:

e.g.

```
$('#mainContent').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.one').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.one').hide();
    }
    TextareaAuto(this);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rz3f3gng/3/

### Update

As you still want the Enter to work (see comment below), just get rid of your `e.preventDefault()`

e.g.

```
$('#mainContent').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('.one').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.one').hide();
    }
    TextareaAuto(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rz3f3gng/4/

Which now means it can be reduced using `toggle()` to

```
$('#mainContent').on('keypress', function(e){
    $('.one').toggle(e.which == 13);
    TextareaAuto(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rz3f3gng/5/

Comment: Don't put your foot in first!

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: The comment was valid without code... Please wait for answers to settle :)

Comment: Still Enter key don't work, My caret portion still remains on the same line where on enter press it should come down. @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: @Vinayak: You have explicitly coded it to ignore the Enter using `e.preventDefault();` Just remove that :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rz3f3gng/4/

Comment: Thabx bro @TrueBlueAussie : )